# How to smoothen the borders

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s73F.jpg
I want to smoothen the borders. They took too pixelated. What can I do? This was created on AutoCAD and then imported into 3Dmax.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about 3dsmax

Comment: I'm sorry if I am asking this in the wrong place but there was a question here on 3dsmax so I thought I would use the same platform.